# Regular expression for dotted string with exception

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, qregularexpression

I'm not sure that is it possible to do in one regex, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

I created the expression:

```
/(?<variable>\w+)((\.(?<method>\w+)\((?<parameter>[^{}%]*)\))|(\.(?<subvariable>\w+)))?/i
```

which helps me to "convert" dotted strings to arrays or call to methods:

```
core.settings => $core['settings'] 
core.set(param1, param2) => $core->set('param1', 'param2')
```

It works very well. But I have no idea how to build a several level expression which will work like this:

1. string: core.settings

```
group <variable> = core  
group <subvariable> = settings
```

2. string: core.get(param)

```
group <variable> = core
group <method> = get
group <parameter> = param
```

3. string core.settings.time

```
group <variable> = core
group <subvariable> = settings.time
```

4. string core.settings.time.set(param)

```
group <variable> = core
group <subvariable> = settings.time
group <method> = set
group <parameter> = param
```

Any ideas? And whether it is generally possible?

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could write out the expected output for examples 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: I hope now it's more understandable now

Comment: I know you asked for it to be purely in regex, but would a PHP function do? Also what are you using to run the regex? Also could it be something like `core.settings.time.set(param).format('Y-m-d')` to account for?

Comment: I'm asking only for regex, parsing matches works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?<variable>\w+)(?:\.(?<subvariable>\w+(?:\.\w+)*))??(?:\.(?<method>\w+)\((?<parameter>[^{}%]*)\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WAGr87/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<variable>\w+)` - Group "variable": one or more word chars
- `(?:\.(?<subvariable>\w+(?:\.\w+)*))??` - zero or one occurrence of `.` and then Group "subvariable" matching one or more word chars followed with zero or more occurrences of a `.` and one or more word chars
- `(?:\.(?<method>\w+)\((?<parameter>[^{}%]*)\))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?<method>\w+)` - Group "method": one or more word chars
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?<parameter>[^{}%]*)` - Group "parameter": zero or more chars other than `{`, `}`, `%`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.